# Can MySQL query be sped up after all JOINs have been properly indexed?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.11, for osx10.11 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

I'm taking over an old project and I've been slowly improving it by adding indexes. But I've run into the limit of what I can do with indexes.

This query takes 8 seconds to run. I'd like to make it faster. When I run EXPLAIN it seems an index is being used on every relevant field.

Any suggestions what else I can do?

```
  mysql> explain 
      -> select ttl.id AS id,
      -> ttl.name AS name,
      -> ttl.updated_at AS last_update_on,
      -> ttl.user_id AS list_creator,
      -> ttl.retailer_nomination_list AS nomination_list,
      -> ttl.created_at AS created_on,
      -> tv.name AS venue_name,
      -> count(distinct tlb.title_id) AS title_count,
      -> count(distinct oa.supplier_id) AS supplier_count,
      -> if  ((u.username = u2.username),
      ->       group_concat(distinct concat(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name) order by u2.first_name ASC separator ', '),
      ->       group_concat(distinct concat(u.first_name, u.last_name, u2.first_name, u2.last_name) separator ',
      '>       ')) AS owners
      -> from   ((((((((((haha_title_lists ttl 
      ->   left join haha_title_list_to_users tltu on  ((ttl.id = tltu.title_list_id))) 
      ->   left join users u on  ((tltu.user_id = u.id))) 
      ->   left join users u2 on  ((tltu.user_id = u2.id))) 
      ->   left join haha_title_list_to_venues tlv on  ((ttl.id = tlv.title_list))) 
      ->   left join haha_venue_properties tvp on  ((tlv.venue_id = tvp.id))) 
      ->   left join haha_venues tv on  ((tvp.venue_id = tv.id)))
      ->   join haha_title_list_to_books tlb on  ((ttl.id = tlb.title_list_id)))
      ->   join wawa_title ot on  ((tlb.title_id = ot.title_id)))
      ->   join wawa_title_to_supplier ota on  ((ot.title_id = ota.title_id)))
      ->   join wawa_supplier oa on  ((ota.supplier_id = oa.supplier_id))) group by ttl.id
      -> 
      -> 
      -> ;
  +----+-------------+-------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------+------+--------------------------+
  | id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                                                          | key                                   | key_len | ref                                   | rows | Extra                    |
  +----+-------------+-------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------+------+--------------------------+
  |  1 | SIMPLE      | ttl   | index  | PRIMARY                                                                | PRIMARY                               | 4       | NULL                                  |    6 |                          |
  |  1 | SIMPLE      | tltu  | ref    | idx_title_list_to_user,haha_title_list_to_users_title_list_id          | idx_title_list_to_user                | 4       | wawa_tidal_development.ttl.id         |    1 | Using index              |
  |  1 | SIMPLE      | u     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                | PRIMARY                               | 4       | wawa_tidal_development.tltu.user_id   |    1 |                          |
  |  1 | SIMPLE      | u2    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                | PRIMARY                               | 4       | wawa_tidal_development.tltu.user_id   |    1 |                          |
  |  1 | SIMPLE      | tlv   | ref    | haha_title_list_to_venues_title_list                                   | haha_title_list_to_venues_title_list  | 5       | wawa_tidal_development.ttl.id         |    1 |                          |
  |  1 | SIMPLE      | tvp   | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                | PRIMARY                               | 4       | wawa_tidal_development.tlv.venue_id   |    1 |                          |
  |  1 | SIMPLE      | tv    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                | PRIMARY                               | 4       | wawa_tidal_development.tvp.venue_id   |    1 |                          |
  |  1 | SIMPLE      | tlb   | ref    | idx_title_list_to_books_title_id,idx_title_list_to_books_title_list_id | idx_title_list_to_books_title_list_id | 4       | wawa_tidal_development.ttl.id         |   49 | Using where              |
  |  1 | SIMPLE      | ot    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                | PRIMARY                               | 4       | wawa_tidal_development.tlb.title_id   |    1 | Using index              |
  |  1 | SIMPLE      | ota   | ref    | PRIMARY,title_id                                                       | title_id                              | 4       | wawa_tidal_development.ot.title_id    |    1 | Using where; Using index |
  |  1 | SIMPLE      | oa    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,wawa_supplier_venue_id_supplier_id                             | PRIMARY                               | 4       | wawa_tidal_development.ota.supplier_id |   1 | Using index              |
  +----+-------------+-------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------+------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: Why are you getting the same `users` twice for each `haha_title_list_to_users`?

Comment: I don't know why that was done. All of this code was written in 2010, and I'm just taking over it as of last week.

Comment: Wow. Now that I look at it, that does look pretty wild.